# Many webapps, one vps

Tags: apache-2.2, virtualhost, port, port-forwarding, sinatra

Might be a noob question, Google and SF searches didn't turn up anything super useful. Could be using the wrong words here.

I've got a vps, with one port 80 app running on it. I'd like to add two other apps, accessible from different domains, to that list.

So something like:

- app1.example.com
- app2.example.com
- exampleexample.com

The one current app is running with sinatra/shotgun, the other two are tbd, might be flask. I'd like to keep them on the same vps.

I know apache has a concept of virtual hosts, but I don't know much more.

I think it'd be pretty awesome if there was a process that sat and listened on :80, and forwarded the request on to different process on different ports depending on the requested domain. I might be asking for too much, though.

Comment: Look into Apache mod_proxy or Nginx as a reverse proxy.

Comment: Apache [mod_proxy documentation](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/mod_proxy.html) and [nginx proxy documentation](http://nginx.com/resources/admin-guide/reverse-proxy/)

Comment: I would use haproxy or apache for this.